# Can JCo3 and JCo2 co-exist in Solaris?

Tags: jco, sapjco3

Can SAP Java connector JCo3 lib and JCo2 lib co-exist in a Solaris/Apache/Tomcat server? I am thinking if I can use JCo3 for a new application without touching existing JCo2 applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! The classes and packages, JAR files and native libraries are independent and have different names, so you can have both loaded at the same time. The API is different though, so your code will have to be different for each.